# How do i read the contents of a csv file specific number of times in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have a csv file that has 100 rows. How do i read this file 2 times (2 * 100) and then stop the flow? I used Loop controller and gave loop count 100 and the loop count in main thread group is 2. Its working good when iam running the test with 1 thread but when i update the number of threads to 10 then the total number of requests are 2000. How do i make my test run only 2 times (iterate my csv file only 2 times with number of threads = 10). Any help is appreciated.enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBy7A.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETT5R.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using default [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) settings when it comes to ["Sharing Mode"](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy/) (each user will read next row on each iteration)

[image]

1. Remove your Loop Controller
2. Amend your Thread Group configuration to have 20 loops:

   [image]

In this case you will have 200 total requests, each line from the CSV file will be hit twice: